# Do GORM / GMongo wrap collections to accept Maps? (Grails / GMongo internals.)

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gmongo

I'm working with Grails Mongo domain objects and I've noticed that I get very different behavior with the following two ways to access a collection:

#### `c1`: collection name is known at compile time:

`def c1 = MyDomainClass.collection`

#### `c2`: collection name is only known at runtime

`def c2 = AnyDomainClass.collection.DB.getCollection(collectionName)`

### `c1` and `c2` have the same class, but behave differently!

Both `c1` and `c2` have the class `com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection` but they behave differently.

Specifically, `c1` supports "friendly" interactions like passing Maps directly to GMongo methods, e.g.

```
c1.find([tag:'spicy']).sort([created:1])
```

Whereas `c2` only works with `DBObject` parameters like:

```
c2.find(new BasicDBObject([tag:'spicy'])).sort(new BasicDBObject([created:1]))
```

I prefer the syntax in #1, and I would like to be able to use that syntax with objects even when I don't know the collection at compile time.  In other words, I want to be able to dynamically access collections (which I can do with #2), but using the "friendly" syntax from #1.

### My questions are:

1. How are `c1` and `c2` different?
2. How can I instantiate collections that behave like `c1` when the collection is unknown at compile time?
3. At what layer of the Grails/GORM/GMongo stack are objects wrapped to support map-to-DBObject conversions, and how is this done?

Comment: Have you tried printing `c1.getClass()` and `c2.getClass()`?

Comment: What a great question! Updated the text above to indicate that both `c1` and `c2` have the same class: `com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection`.

Comment: In second question, what did you mean by "when the collection is unknown at compile time"? Did you mean the domain class is dynamic at run time?